# Insert data to MySQL table every second (one time per second)

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

i'm new in Python, Raspberry Pi and MySQL and i hope that you can help me. I'm trying to write a script in Python that could insert data every second into a MySQL table. I can insert data but is not periodical like i want, I already tried a lot and i can't find the solution to my problem. Here goes my Python code and the data inserted into the MySQL table:

#### Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import MySQLdb
import time

while True:
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "mauro", "12345", "temps")
    curs=db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute ("""INSERT INTO thetemps 
                values(0, CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), 28)""")
        db.commit()
        print "Data committed"
    except:
        print "Error"
        db.rollback()
    db.close()
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### Table Result:

```
+-----+------------+----------+------+
| id  | date       | time     | temp |
+-----+------------+----------+------+
| 107 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:41 |   28 |
| 108 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:42 |   28 |
| 109 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:45 |   28 |
| 110 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:46 |   28 |
| 111 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:47 |   28 |
| 112 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:48 |   28 |
| 113 | 2015-11-06 | 19:16:56 |   28 |
| 114 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:00 |   28 |
| 115 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:03 |   28 |
| 116 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:05 |   28 |
| 117 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:06 |   28 |
| 118 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:07 |   28 |
| 119 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:08 |   28 |
| 120 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:09 |   28 |
| 121 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:10 |   28 |
| 122 | 2015-11-06 | 19:17:11 |   28 |
+-----+------------+----------+------+
```

As you can see, sometimes the scrip insert data periodicaly, and sometimes we have 8 seconds of interval between the data. So, my question is: is possible to the interval between the data be 1 second every time? What am i doing wrong?
Sorry for the bad english and thanks in advance!

Comment: put the `.connect` and `.close` outside of the while loop so it doesnt need to reinitialize every time. this doesn't ensure anything but it may be more consistent. another thing you can do is instead of having a `time.sleep` you can read in the last time value in the table then execute your command when its been a second after that

Comment: To figure out exactly what is going on you need to strace (use -tt to get timestamps) both your python process and mysqld. If you just want to guess, in addition to what has been already said, ```ALTER TABLE thetemps ENGINE=MYISAM``` if the table is InnoDB. Raspberry PI might not have enough umph to deal with InnoDB tables effectively. Transaction commit might be taking a while.

Comment: Please, don't forget to come back and accept an answer that you find most useful to you. It benefits you, those trying to solve your problem, and the rest of the community at large.

Comment: Thanks @ SashaPachev!! This make my script work as i want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're establishing a new connection to the database server on each iteration. This can take arbitrary amount of time. Moving `.connect()`, etc. outside of the loop may give you more consistent timings:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "mauro", "12345", "temps")
curs = db.cursor()

while True:    
    try:
        curs.execute ("""INSERT INTO thetemps 
                values(0, CURRENT_DATE(), NOW(), 28)""")
        db.commit()
        print "Data committed"
    except:
        print "Error"
        db.rollback()    
    time.sleep(1)
db.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did this and the script gets better, but not 100%, then i did what  Sasha Pachev said above, i changed the engine to MYISAM  and now the script is working as i want!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use transaction for this, maybe some table are locked, when attempt to insert new row.

Answer (score 1):

> is possible to the interval between the data be 1 second every time?

Theoretically, yes, but in practice there're too many other factors outside of your control that are more likely to get in the way. Some of these include, but are not limited to:

1. OS kernel's task scheduler
2. Task priorities relative to others
3. Overall system load
4. Amount of data already in the table (check time complexity of binary trees)

This means that even if your system was idle most of the time, the `time.sleep(1)` is not guaranteed to always sleep for *exactly* 1 second, and even if it did, the system may've been doing something else (e.g. more I/O) and require different amounts of time to perform the same operations every time.

Also, instead of creating a *new* connection every time inside the loop, you should keep the connection open and save the overhead.

> What am i doing wrong?

I don't think you're doing anything particularly wrong here. The code looks OK, **except** for the extra overhead of creating a new connection every time --which you *shouldn't*. That aside, the issue here boils down to factors outside of your control.

That being said, there're some things you can do to improve your chances.

---

### A few additional suggestions to improve performance

#### Storage Engine

In addition to avoiding the overhead of opening/closing the database connection on every iteration, you should check the storage engine used for the table. For example, depending on your MySQL version, the default might still be `MyISAM`, which requires *table* locking for writing.

In contrast, `InnoDB` only requires *row* locking when writing to the table, which should improve things if something else is using the table. If you find you're not using `InnoDB`, issue an `alter table ...` query to change the storage engine.

#### Auto-Commit instead of Transaction

Transactions are meant to group a *set* of 2 or more queries as a single unit, but you're submitting *individual* queries. Instead, you should configure MySQL to have automatic commits enabled, so that it doesn't have to wait for an explicit `commit` request after your query is submitted and executed, saving some communication overhead between the server and your client.

#### Influence the OS Scheduler by Increasing Your Priority

You can set a higher priority for your program in order for the scheduler to be more helpful here. It might also help doing the same thing for the database service/process.

Other *user*-level tasks could also have their priorities lowered a bit, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try create the connection to the db before while condition to keep open the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that connecting + inserting takes time, this will add up and your process will eventually behind.

What I would do is separate the data gathering (make sure you read your temperatures every second) from the data loading (data loading can take longer than a second if needed, but you won't fall behind).

So, if I were you, I'd have two separate scripts running in parallel and communicating through some simple, fast and reliable mechanism. A list in [Redis](http://redis.io/) would probably work great. You could also use something like [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/).

Something like this:

```
# gather.py
while True:
    temp = get_temp()
    redis.lpush('temps', pickle.dumps([temp, datetime.now]))
    time.sleep(1)
```

and..

```
# load.py
while True:
    # Block until new temps are available in redis
    data, key = redis.brpop('temps')
    # Get all temps queued
    datapoints = [data] +  redis.rpop('temps'):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "mauro", "12345", "temps")
    curs=db.cursor()
    try:
        for p in datapoints:
            point = pickle.loads(p)
            curs.execute ("INSERT INTO thetemps (temp, timestamp) values({}, {})".format(point[0], point[1])
        db.commit()
        print "Data committed"
    except:
        print "Error"
        db.rollback()
```

You could add some improvements on the above like reusing the db connection, making sure you don't lose the temps if there's a DB error, using a namedtuple instead of an array for the datapoints, etc.

Comment: +1 for the idea, although I think the implementation ^^ has the same problem as the OP: `connect()`, etc. can take arbitrary amount of time and the timestamps (`NOW()`) can differ by more that 1s.

Comment: @eugeney yeah, I re-read the code and there were a bunch of mistakes. Tried to fixed them even though its more of a general idea than actual working code :-)